# Group rows based on time interval on Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group the rows of a data frame based on the time difference between them.

If the records differ by less than 30 days (time interval), they must be grouped together; otherwise, they are considered separate events. The start will be equal to the start date of the first record, and the end will be equal to the end date of the last record.

**For example**: The following dataframe

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-10 | 2023-09-01 |
| 1 | 2023-09-20 | 2023-10-14 |
| 1 | 2023-11-20 | 2023-12-27 |
| 2 | 2023-08-15 | 2023-09-05 |
| 2 | 2023-09-20 | 2023-10-14 |
| 2 | 2023-11-01 | 2023-12-20 |

should become like this:

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-10 | 2023-10-14 |
| 1 | 2023-11-20 | 2023-12-27 |
| 2 | 2023-08-15 | 2023-12-20 |

For the first case, the first two records should be grouped together as:

start_2n_row - end_1st_row = 2023-09-20 - 2023-09-01 = 19 days

though the 3rd record should be considered a separate event.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'id': [1, 2, 1, 1,  2, 2],
'start': ['2023-08-10', '2023-08-15', '2023-09-20', '2023-11-20', '2023-09-20', '2023-11-01'],
'end': ['2023-09-01', '2023-09-05', '2023-10-14', '2023-12-27',  '2023-10-14', '2023-12-20']
})
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to test the below answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) to access the previous end per group, then [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
delta = '30D'

# ensure datetime
df[['start', 'end']] = df[['start', 'end']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# group values that are within 30D in a group
group = (df['start'].sub(df.groupby('id')['end'].shift())
         .gt(delta).groupby(df['id']).cumsum()
        )

# aggregate
out = (df.groupby(['id', group], as_index=False)
         .agg({'start': 'min', 'end': 'max'})
      )
```

Output:

```
   id      start        end
0   1 2023-08-10 2023-10-14
1   1 2023-11-20 2023-12-27
2   2 2023-08-15 2023-12-20
```

Comment: @GrigorisPapapostolou possibly, but this could be a different logic, maybe worth opening a new question explaining all the details (as you did for this one).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta


data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'start': pd.to_datetime(['1990-08-10', '1990-08-15', '1990-09-20', '1990-11-20', '1990-09-20', '1990-11-01']),
    'end': pd.to_datetime(['1990-09-01', '1990-09-05', '1990-10-14', '1990-12-27', '1990-10-14', '1990-12-20'])
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
"""
   id      start        end
0   1 1990-08-10 1990-09-01
1   2 1990-08-15 1990-09-05
2   1 1990-09-20 1990-10-14
3   1 1990-11-20 1990-12-27
4   2 1990-09-20 1990-10-14
5   2 1990-11-01 1990-12-20

"""

threshold = timedelta(days=30)

time_diffs = np.maximum(df['start'] - df.groupby('id')['end'].shift(), np.timedelta64(0, 'D'))
print(time_diffs)
"""
0       NaT
1       NaT
2   19 days
3   37 days
4   15 days
5   18 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
"""
group_mask = (time_diffs > threshold).where(df['id'].duplicated(), False)
print(group_mask)
"""
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool"""

df['group'] = group_mask
res = df.groupby(['id', 'group'], as_index=False).agg({'start': 'min', 'end': 'max'}).drop('group', axis=1)

print(res)
""" 
 id      start        end
0   1 1990-08-10 1990-10-14
1   1 1990-11-20 1990-12-27
2   2 1990-08-15 1990-12-20
"""
```