# Group rows based on time interval on pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to categorize rows in a data frame by considering the time span between them. Rows where the time difference is less than 30 days should be classified into one group, indicating they are part of the same event. Conversely, records with a time difference greater than 30 days are treated as distinct events. In each group, the initial date will be set as the start date from the first entry, and the end date will be the start date of the final entry in that group. For events that are not combined into groups, the start and end dates will be identical.

**For example**: The following dataframe

| id | start |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-10 |
| 1 | 2023-09-20 |
| 1 | 2023-12-20 |
| 2 | 2023-08-15 |
| 2 | 2023-09-20 |
| 2 | 2023-11-25 |

should become like this:

| id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-10 | 2023-09-20 |
| 1 | 2023-12-20 | 2023-12-20 |
| 2 | 2023-08-15 | 2023-09-20 |
| 2 | 2023-11-25 | 2023-11-25 |

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'id': [1, 2, 1, 1,  2, 2],
'start': ['2023-08-10', '2023-08-15', '2023-09-20', '2023-11-20', '2023-09-20', '2023-11-01'],
})
```

Based on a similar answer, what should be done is as follows:

```
delta = '30D'

# ensure datetime
df['start'] = df['start'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
# create new column
df['end'] = df['start']

# group values that are within 30D in a group
group = (df['start'].sub(df.groupby('id')['end'].shift()).gt(delta).groupby(df['id']).cumsum())

# aggregate
out = (df.groupby(['id', group], as_index=False).agg({'start': 'min', 'end': 'max'}))
```

However, the solution mentioned earlier resulted in separate, individual records.

Comment: @mozway credits for his answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77006450/group-rows-based-on-time-interval-on-pandas-dataframe)  

Comment: I don't see how this is different from the original question. In your comment you mentioned NaNs, which is not the case here.

Comment: Thank you for updating, I believe the output/logic is incorrect here. `2023-09-20` is not within 30D of `2023-08-10`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after:

```
# aggregate
out2 = pd.concat([group, df],axis=1)
out2.groupby([0], as_index=False).agg({'start': 'min', 'end': 'max'})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
grp = df['start'].sub(df.groupby('id')['end'].shift()).gt('30days')\
                 .groupby(df['id']).cumsum()
out = df.groupby(['id', grp])['start'].agg(start='first', end='last')\
        .droplevel(1).reset_index()
```

out

```
    id  start   end
0   1   2023-08-10  2023-09-20
1   1   2023-11-20  2023-11-20
2   2   2023-08-15  2023-09-20
3   2   2023-11-25  2023-11-25
```

**Example Code**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'id': [1, 2, 1, 1,  2, 2],
'start': ['2023-08-10', '2023-08-15', '2023-09-20', '2023-11-20', '2023-09-20', '2023-11-25'],
'end': ['2023-09-01', '2023-09-05', '2023-10-14', '2023-12-27',  '2023-10-14', '2023-12-20']
})
```

i think that last value of start column may be '2023-11-25'  (not '2023-11-01')

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't really make sense with a 30D threshold. I'll assume 45D here.

As in the other question, you can craft a grouper with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), then [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html)
:

```
delta = '45D'

# ensure datetime
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])

# group values that are within 30D in an ID in a group
group = (df.groupby('id')['start']
           .transform(lambda g: g.diff().ge(delta)
                                 .cumsum())
        )

# aggregate
out = (df.groupby(['id', group], as_index=False)
         .agg(**{'start': ('start', 'min'),
                 'end': ('start', 'max'),
                })
      )
```

Output:

```
   id      start        end
0   1 2023-08-10 2023-09-20
1   1 2023-11-20 2023-11-20
2   2 2023-08-15 2023-11-01
```